# In iTerm2 Command Click on URLS does not work when inside a tmux session

Tags: terminal, mouse, iterm, tmux

When not inside a tmux session, `Command-Click` on URLs works flawlessly.

How can I make links clickable in **iTerm2** when inside a tmux session?
When hitting `Command` the mouse pointer changes to the [image: hand pointer] icon, but when clicking on an URL, nothing happens.

Note I have the following settings inside my `.tmux.conf`

```
[...]
# Enable mouse mode
set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on

# Mouse pane switching
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
[...]
```

Disabling them and then reloading `.tmux.conf` does not resolve the issue.

iTerm2 Version is `Build 1.0.0.20140629`
tmux -V 1.9a

Comment: If you upgrade to 2.0 this works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To use the normal mouse behavior in `tmux` you have to keep `alt` pressed. So click on the link while pressing `cmd`+`alt`. The same applies when selecting text.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but your suggestion does not work for me.

Comment: Ah, I only figure it out now. You have iTerm2 1.0. That's probably why it doesn't work for you. I'm using 2.0.

Comment: I just realized that it does now!
Thx for the gif! I have no clue what is different now though. :)

Comment: What software did you use to create the gif?

Comment: @elementz I used [this script](https://github.com/jclem/gifify).

Comment: good to know. thx.

Comment: Rnhmjoj , @jottr Has anyone made any headway on getting this to work for iTerm versions > 2.0?

Comment: The answer on windows/mintty is ctrl+shift+click

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue today. I would command-click on a URL in iTerm2 (Mac) and the app would seemingly lose focus but the link wouldn't open in a browser (Chrome, in my case). This used to work fine for me so I was a little confused and the other answers here didn't work for me.

It seemed to me that Chrome was "trying" to open but failing for some reason. I ran `ps -ax | grep -i chrome` to get a list of the Chrome or Chrome-related processes that were running and sure enough there was a process running that didn't correspond to an application that I was actively using.

Long story short, I killed all the Chrome-related processes and command-click worked again.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer may work when using regular tmux, but it will not work when using [iTerm2+tmux integration](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/wikis/TmuxIntegration) with the `-CC` option. For Cmd+Click to use your "Semantic History" Profile Preference, you have to install [iTerm2 Shell Integration](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html). Also I have found it best to create a seperate `.tmux.conf.iterm` with tmux integration, then create aliases for creating and attaching integrated sessions.

```
alias tcs="tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf.iterm -CC new -s"
alias tca="tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf.iterm -CC attach -t"
```

The only think in my `~/.tmux.conf.iterm` file is `set-option -g default-terminal screen-256color`